# GROUP BY date error after update to MySQL 5.7

Tags: group-by, mysql-5.7

I have a simple script that counts form leads and displays the counts by month and year. It worked fine until I upgraded to MySQL 5.7. Now I get this error:

*There was an error running the query [Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'form.form_25.submission_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]*

My query is:

```
SELECT YEAR(`submission_date`) AS yr, 
MONTH(`submission_date`) AS mth,
DATE_FORMAT(`submission_date`,'%M %Y') AS display_date, 
COUNT(*) AS leadcount
FROM form_25 
WHERE `submission_date` >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY yr,mth
ORDER BY yr DESC, mth DESC
```

I realize this is because only_full_group_by is enabled, but I don't want to disable it.

I've researched this problem, but it seems like all of the suggested solutions are about grouping by a unique column. That isn't a solution in this case because grouping by my primary column does not display the lead counts properly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you want to disable it?

Comment: @Tofandel, I'm assuming that if it's set on by default in this version. it will be required in future versions. Also, on some of my clients I can't disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out a solution that is good enough for my purposes. I discovered that the error only happens when this line is included:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`submission_date`,'%M %Y') AS display_date,
```

So I removed that line and recreated the display_date variable in PHP by using the yr and mth aliases.